# SwiftUI GKLeaderboard loadEntries

Tags: swiftui, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I would like to add leaderboards to my SwiftUI app.
I can't find any examples of using loadEntries to load leaderboard values.
I tried the following...

```
let leaderBoard: GKLeaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
leaderBoard.identifier = "YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID_HERE"
leaderBoard.timeScope = .allTime
leaderBoard.loadScores { (scores, error) in ...
```

This results in the following warnings:

- 'identifier' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Use
  loadEntriesForPlayerScope:timeScope:range:completionHandler: instead.
- 'timeScope' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Use
  loadEntriesForPlayerScope:timeScope:range:completionHandler: instead.
- 'loadScores(completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Use
  loadEntriesForPlayerScope:timeScope:range:completionHandler:.

using loadEntriesForPlayerScope results in the following warning:

- 'loadEntriesForPlayerScope(_:timeScope:range:completionHandler:)' has
  been renamed to 'loadEntries(for:timeScope:range:completionHandler:)'

Using **loadEntries** I don't know how to specify the leaderboard identifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is simple demo of possible approach - put everything in view model and load scores on view appear.

```
import GameKit

class BoardModel: ObservableObject {
    private var board: GKLeaderboard?
    @Published var localPlayerScore: GKLeaderboard.Entry?
    @Published var topScores: [GKLeaderboard.Entry]?
    
    func load() {
        if nil == board {
            GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboards(IDs: ["YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID_HERE"]) { [weak self] (boards, error) in
                self?.board = boards?.first
                self?.updateScores()
            }
        } else {
            self.updateScores()
        }
    }
    
    func updateScores() {
        board?.loadEntries(for: .global, timeScope: .allTime, range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 10),
            completionHandler: { [weak self] (local, entries, count, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.localPlayerScore = local
                self?.topScores = entries
            }
        })
    }
}

struct DemoGameboardview: View {
    @StateObject var vm = BoardModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vm.topScores ?? [], id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.player.displayName)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(item.formattedScore)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.load()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to test this out because I had to work out how to authenticate the user first.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I might be stating the obvious but have you looked at the WWDC20 videos?
Usually when there are big changes like this they cover it during WWDC that year.

[Tap into Game Center: Leaderboards, Achievements, and Multiplayer](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10619)

[Tap into Game Center: Dashboard, Access Point, and Profile](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10618)

I haven't looked at the videos but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard) eludes that `identifier` might be replaced by [`var baseLeaderboardID: String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/3547256-baseleaderboardid)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll watch those.  I can't set baseLeaderboardID.  It's a get-only property.